# Money-market model: Income rises, bond prices fall. But if income rises, saving increases — in bonds. So why does rising income lower bond prices?

Tags: macroeconomics, interest-rate, money-supply, money, bonds

According to [the money market model](https://www.khanacademy.org/economics-finance-domain/ap-macroeconomics/ap-macro-resources-and-exam-preparation/every-graph-used-in-ap-macroeconomics/a/the-money-market-model) that determines the equilibrium interest rate at which the demand for money in the economy equals the supply of money: when the money demand curve shifts right for some reason, the interest rate increases. In other words: bond prices fall. [(Here's a reference graphic I made.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ba7RU.png) One of those reasons is that national income increases.

But if I imagine people's incomes increasing in real life, then while I can picture them wanting to hold more money for increased spending, I can *also* imagine them saying to themselves, "Now I can put more money away for a rainy day in an interest-bearing account that the bank can use to buy bonds." If my income sits at \$5000 a month and then I get an extra \$500 a month, I might spend an extra \$300 and save the remaining extra \$200 in one such account. If people increase spending *and* saving, then *both* the demand for money *and* the demand for bonds will increase. If the demand for bonds increases, then their price will increase, and their interest rates will fall. So why does the model claim that bond interest rates rise instead?

I'm sure I'm missing something incredibly simple here. Please help.